# Drag and drop animation

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-animation

I am using onDragListener for handling drag and drop view. Currently I drag view and drop some other position. When view not drop properly it moves back to original position with animation. I Apply some condition logic in **DragEvent.ACTION_DROP** event of **onDrag()** method. I want that when view drop condition logic is false it come back to original position with animation.